# Can I compile a smart contract without removing the line breaks?

Tags: solidity, greeter, compilation

According to an official document, compiling a smart contract needs to remove all the line-breaks in the [contract's source-code](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/contract_greeter.html):

> If you have the SolC Solidity Compiler installed, you need now reformat by removing spaces so it fits into a string variable.

```
var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
```

As I think the removing process is not *smart*, I want to compile the code itself without stripping the line break manually.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My advice would be to use the [Browser Solidity](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/):

Just copy paste your contract, and if it compiles without errors you can just copy past the content of Web3 deploy:

```
var _numProposals = /* var of type uint8 here */ ;
var ballotContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winningProposal","outputs":[{"name":"winningProposal","type":"uint8"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"giveRightToVote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"proposal","type":"uint8"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_numProposals","type":"uint8"}],"type":"constructor"}]);
var ballot = ballotContract.new(
   _numProposals,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '60606040*deleted-for-lsibility-6', 
     gas: 3000000
   }, function(e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Don't forget that :

- It's javascript ( so address is string )
- You need to fill your params `var _numProposals = /* var of type uint8 here */ ;`  here.

--

Another solution is Mix IDE :

Click on Deploy then click on Open Compilation Result and it will provide you with a JS file. Inside there are objects representing your contract. You would then need to call web3.eth.contract(Mycontract.abi)

Answer (score 3):

Heres a javascript command that will strip newlines

```
xmlStr = xmlStr .replace(/\n/gi, "");  // strip newlines
```